# Tagret parent of parent on click Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<div class="parent-portlet
     ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)">
    <div class="portlet-titlebar" ng-click="toggleCollapsed($event)">
        <span class="remove" ng-click="removePortlet()">
               Remove
        </span>
        <span class="add-back" ng-click="addPortlet()">
               Add Back
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to somehow catch the "parent-portlet" element when either of the spans are clicked. That is the parent of their parent. Is there a way similar to:

> angular.element(event.currentTarget).parentElement();

to do that, but for the parent of the parent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you already have that in angular. then what you want now?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery use this code

```
$(“span”).on(“click”,function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```

Note:- here I use span tag as a selector change it

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution using jQuery

```js
$('span').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('div.parent-portlet').attr('class'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-portlet
     ng-mouseenter="hoverIn($event)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($event)">
    <div class="portlet-titlebar" ng-click="toggleCollapsed($event)">
        <span class="remove">
               Remove
        </span>
        <span class="add-back">
               Add Back
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.